# fiddler shortcut for Browse in chrome

Tags: fiddler

[image]

Are there any shortcut for browsing in chrome?Or if there any software could help set shortcuts by ourselves.

Comment: When you click the dropdown arrow, does Chrome appear in the list of browsers?

Comment: yes,Chrome appears.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing the `Chrome` entry in the browser dropdown will open Chrome instead of IE. Surprisingly, there's presently [no public way](https://fiddler.ideas.aha.io/ideas/FID-I-192) of changing the default browser, although I'm guessing that Telerik will fix this eventually.

If this is a big problem for you, you could use the `BindUIButton` attribute on a FiddlerScript method to add a new toolbar button that does just that. Or you can create a QuickLink menu with the commands of your choice, e.g.

```
 QuickLinkMenu("&Browse")
 QuickLinkItem("&IE", "iexplore.exe")
 QuickLinkItem("&Firefox", "firefox.exe")
 QuickLinkItem("&Opera", "Opera.exe")
 QuickLinkItem("&Chrome", "Chrome.exe")
 public static function DoBrowsersMenu(sText: String, sAction: String)
 {
   var oS = FiddlerApplication.UI.GetSelectedSessions();
   var sURL = String.Empty;
   if (oS.Length > 0) { sURL = oS[0].fullUrl; }
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sAction, sURL);
 }
```